# I am not able to push the code

Tags: github

```
Counting objects: 26, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (26/26), 12.03 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 26 (delta 16), reused 3 (delta 1)
remote: 
remote: One of your commit messages is missing an issue ID:
remote: 
remote:   13f7efa: RED-fleet-integration implement new jfa schema
remote: 
remote: For more information, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/ZwjoE.
remote: 
To git@bitbucket.org:mba-rb/redbook.git
 ! [remote rejected] RED-fleet-integration -> RED-fleet-integration (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:mba-rb/redbook.git'
```

Comment: Did you read the errors? `One of your commit messages is missing an issue ID`

Comment: `One of your commit messages is missing an issue ID`
Seem to be an intern problem not relative to git

Comment: Why People are down voting his question. If he knows everything then why should people use community?

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues assigned in your git repository.
So when you are going to push the code, please add Issue Id in your commit message. Like:

```
Issue Id: 3
```

Your Commit message is:

```
commit xyz
```

Then Your Final Commit Message Should be:

```
#3 commit xyz
```

or

```
commit xyz #3
```

or

```
commit #3 xyz
```